# Why do i get "position_dodge requires constant width" even though widths are constant in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm getting a warning message I don't understand for simple bar charts in ggplot2

```
> df <- data.frame(X = 127:131, Y = rnorm(5))
> df
    X          Y
1 127  0.9391077
2 128 -0.9392529
3 129 -1.1296221
4 130  1.1454907
5 131  1.8564596
> ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(X,Y), stat ="identity", position = "dodge")
Warning message:
position_dodge requires constant width: output may be incorrect
```

It only seems to happen for certain ranges of X values.  I've googled for info on this, but it all seems to be talking about cases when the widths genuinely are different, or cases where stat is not "identity".  In this case the X values are just integers, so it should be simple.

The chart produced looks ok, so I'm uneasy about just ignoring a warning I don't understand.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: I've submitted an issue about the dodgy warning on github. https://github.com/hadley/scales/issues/33

Comment: This has now been fixed in the development version of `scales`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Setting [`options(warn = 2, error = recover)`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/recover), and rerunning the code lets us find the problem.

Inside the `collide` function (number 16 in the call stack), there is this piece of code:

```
if (!zero_range(range(widths))) {
    warning(name, " requires constant width: output may be incorrect", 
        call. = FALSE)
}
```

[Floating point rounding errors](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) mean that `widths` takes slightly different values.

```
format(widths, digits = 22)
# [1] "0.9000000000000056843419" "0.8999999999999914734872" "0.8999999999999772626325"
```

The [tolerance](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/scales/docs/zero_range) for checking that the numbers are the same is too strict: about 2.2e-14.

```
args(zero_range)
# function (x, tol = .Machine$double.eps * 100) 
# NULL
.Machine$double.eps * 100
# [1] 2.220446e-14
```

So the warning is erroneous; don't worry about it.