# Error with facet_wrap since updating ggplot2 to 1.0.1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a code snipped which worked fine since last week when I updated `ggplot2` from `0.9.3` to `1.0.1`.

So basically here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(values=rnorm(200000),
                 title=rep(seq(1,20), each=10000))
ggplot(df, aes(values)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.08) + facet_wrap(~ title)
ggplot(df, aes(values)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.05) + facet_wrap(~ title)
```

In version `0.9.3` it worked with `binwidth=.05`. Now it returns an error:

```
Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 238, 207
```

I am wondering how to calculate the binwidth in a save way so it will not exit. The standard setting is actually not fine enough for my taste.

Also there are a lot of warning messages which I not completely understand:

```
1: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Since after a few tests, it seems to work for me sometimes and sometimes not, I also used a seed to make everything reproducible... But in the end, even with a seed, sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this? I never had problems before updating. Here is the complete output:

```
> set.seed(123)
> df <- data.frame(values=rnorm(200000),
+                  title=rep(seq(1,20), each=10000))
> ggplot(df, aes(values)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.05) + facet_wrap(~ title)
Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 188, 177
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
2: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
3: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
4: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
5: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
6: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
> ggplot(df, aes(values)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.08) + facet_wrap(~ title)
> set.seed(123)
> df <- data.frame(values=rnorm(200000),
+                  title=rep(seq(1,20), each=10000))
> ggplot(df, aes(values)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.05) + facet_wrap(~ title)
There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> ggplot(df, aes(values)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.08) + facet_wrap(~ title)
```

As you can see, only the first ggplot command gives an error. And after recreating the same data frame, it works and only produces some warnings.

Maybe someone has an idea how to narrow the problem a bit?

Comment: It worked without an error for me for both Version 1.0.1 and 1.0.0

Comment: strange, I added a seed to 1234 and now it works for me as well... :-/ Have to find a seed where it isn't working...

Comment: regarding the warnings, I think you shouldn't worry about it, and it's probably a variation of:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476961/why-do-i-get-position-dodge-requires-constant-width-even-though-widths-are-con

Comment: Including your session info in your question may help here.  I think the `In loop_apply(n, do.ply) ` part of the the warnings is a clue that may point to package plyr.  If I load plyr version 1.8.2 I can reproduce your problem.  If I don't load it I don't seem to have the problem.  Also if I update to the development version of plyr (1.8.2.9000) the issue appears to go away even with plyr loaded.

Comment: I also use the plyr version 1.8.2 package. Will update to the development version and will give it some tries...

Comment: @aosmith post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning includes `In loop_apply(n, do.ply)`, which indicates that package **plyr** might be involved in whatever is going on.  When I loaded package **plyr_1.8.2** I could reproduce the error.

Updating to the current development version, **plyr_1.8.2.9000**, solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is `plyr` related. Updating to the development version `1.8.2.9000` solved the issue. Thanks @aosmith for pointing this out!

Comment: You are right but I couldn't find a way to encourage... I was checking if I can give the bounty to a comment, but this isn't working... Is there a way to address people directly? I was expecting @ will do something like this... So please aosmith, write an answer and I will grand you the bounty...